# What is the name for an explanatory item response model where the predictors include latent variables?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, measurement-error, latent-variable, item-response-theory

Explanatory item response models add predictors of the $\theta$ "ability" parameter. However, these predictors are always observed covariates. Sometimes, one may want to include latent variables as predictors, such as a different dimension representing a different type of ability. This is the item response theory equivalent to a structural equation model.

What is the name for this model? Any resources suggested for learning more?

Comment: in educational assessment context this is often done using plausible value representations of said constructs.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you are asking for information regarding an IRT model where a latent variable $\theta_y$ can be regressed onto one or more **latent** predictor variables $\theta_x$, correct? I am unaware of any formal presentation of such a model, though it should be pretty straightforward in a Bayesian framework using probabilistic programming languages (e.g., `jags`, `stan`).

One article (Lu, Thomas, & Zumbo, 2005) does come close to what you are looking for. First, they estimate the SEM's measurement model parameters using IRT. Second, they convert IRT parameters to their CFA/SEM parameterization$^1$; and third, they keep these parameters **fixed** during the estimation of structural parameters using SEM software.

$^1$ See Takane & De Leeuw (1987) for more information on the relationship between IRT and factor analysis of categorical data.

**References**

Lu, I. R., Thomas, D. R., & Zumbo, B. D. (2005). Embedding IRT in structural equation models: A comparison with regression based on IRT scores. Structural Equation Modeling, 12(2), 263-277.

Takane, Y., & De Leeuw, J. (1987). On the relationship between item response theory and factor analysis of discretized variables. Psychometrika, 52(3), 393-408.

Comment: Come across the first paper quite a bit but nowhere subscribes to that journal!

Comment: Note: this appears do-able within the context of latent-variable linear mixed models. See page 383 here https://www.routledge.com/Longitudinal-Data-Analysis/Fitzmaurice-Davidian-Verbeke-Molenberghs/p/book/9781584886587

Comment: Glad it helped! I don’t have access to the book you referenced, but I will take a look when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

See Boeck and Wilson (2004): https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3990-9

There is no special name for this. It is just an (possibly double) explanatory item response model.